# What do you call the percentage of a number within a range?

Tags: terminology

I often need to calculate the position of a number $n$ on a scale from $a$ to $b$, represented as a value between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive), as shown below:
$$
p=\frac{n - a}{b - a}
$$
Where $a \leq n \leq b \therefore 0 \leq p \leq 1$

Is there a general mathematical term for the percentage value $p$?

**Edit:** Alternatively, is there a name for the function I used?
$$F(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

Comment: If $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function for the uniform distribution on $(a,b)$, then $p = F(n)$. I'm not aware of any special name for $p$. Although it's not the same thing, a somewhat related concept is a percentile [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

Comment: You can say that $p$ is the result of **scaling** $x$ in the interval $[a,b]$.